# Create file from Byte Array sent inside JSON Object kotlin

Tags: android, arrays, kotlin, fileoutputstream

I have a JSON Object that contains an array of bytes. That array of bytes should create a file. I have done this in iOS and it works, however, trying to do the same task in Android, the text in the resulting file is completely different. I have found plenty of questions and solutions for writing the byteArray to file, and after trying about 6 approaches, so far, this is my solution (probably not the best one I tried, but they all outputted the same content for the file:

```
val bytes: ByteArray = (json["Data"] as JsonArray<Byte>).toByteArray()
val bufferedOut = BufferedOutputStream(FileOutputStream(file)) 
val output = DataOutputStream(bufferedOut)
output.write(bytes)
output.close()
```

I have compared the byteArray (I know in this formula of my code it's a list of Int's but it's a shorter way of safely casting from a `klaxon JsonObject`) between the working iOS version and this one and they match perfectly. However, the output it's completely different and a bunch of gibberish in Android.

I keep thinking the encoding must be different, but I have read some answers for similar questions where people were saying that Java doesn't use encoding, so where an I going wrong?

EDIT: After comparing more in depth the iOS vs Android process, I notice in iOS it's writing Data to File and that Data is the same as the text coming out in the Android Document. So I tried to convert that data into a DataOutputStream and write the bytes through it (updated code). In my head it made sense when I wrote it but the result is the same. It might help to see the "text" so here's the output:

> {\rtf1\deff0{\fonttbl{\f0 Calibri;}}{\colortbl ;\red0\green0\blue255 ;}{*\defchp \fs22}{\stylesheet {\ql\fs22 Normal;}{*\cs1\fs22 Default Paragraph Font;}{*\cs2\sbasedon1\fs22 Line Number;}{*\cs3\ul\fs22\cf1 Hyperlink;}{*\ts4\tsrowd\fs22\ql\tscellpaddfl3\tscellpaddl108\tscellpaddfb3\tscellpaddfr3\tscellpaddr108\tscellpaddft3\tsvertalt\cltxlrtb Normal Table;}{*\ts5\tsrowd\sbasedon4\fs22\ql\trbrdrt\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrl\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrb\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrr\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrh\brdrs\brdrw10\trbrdrv\brdrs\brdrw10\tscellpaddfl3\tscellpaddl108\tscellpaddfr3\tscellpaddr108\tsvertalt\cltxlrtb Table Simple 1;}}{*\listoverridetable}{\info{\creatim\yr2017\mo1\dy23\hr12\min44}{\version1}}\nouicompat\splytwnine\htmautsp\sectd\pard\plain\ql\fs22\par}

Also, this is code for sharing the file to a text editor:

```
val shareIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(file))
shareIntent.type = "text/*"
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Save file in..."))
```

Everything is done according to Kotlin Coroutines, so the async aspect is taken care of and not part of the problem.

Comment: You should use Byte instead of Int, like List<Byte>

Comment: But FileOutputStream requires Int or ByteArray as arguments. That's why I left it as an Int, since file text is same as when I had it as a ByteArray.